How to get commit message for current PR in azure devops instead of "Merge pull request"
I was given the task to enforce semantic versioning on our azure devops pipeline and I'm struggling to find a way to get the PR commit message.
This is the format we are going for

feat(EMV-000): this commit will do stuff

This is every way I've tried to get the commit message from the pr, while doing research:
git log --format=%B -n 1
git log -1 --pretty=format:%s ${gitCommitId})
git log -n 1 ${branchName}
git log -1 --format=%H --grep=$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)
git log -1 --format=%P $(Build.SourceVersion)
git rev-parse $(Build.SourceVersion)^
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit -n 1 --merges $(Build.SourceVersion)
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit -n 1 $(Build.SourceVersion)
git log --no-merges --first-parent -n 1
git log -1 --format=%s

running these locally I get the desired output:

chore(EMV-186): this commit will be approved by the pipeline

running these on the pipeline I get:

Merge pull request 61 from enforce_git_message into develop

Maybe its relevant to know that we squash our commits and rebase our branches.
Below is the way I am trying to run the script on the azure pipelines yml
- script: |
    COMMIT_MSG=$(git log -1 --format=%s)
    echo "Commit message: $COMMIT_MSG"
    if [[ $COMMIT_MSG =~ ^(feat|fix|chore|docs|style|refactor|test|build|ci|perf) ]]; then
      echo "Commit message type is valid"
    else
      echo "Error: Commit message must start with one of the following: feat, fix, chore, docs, style, refactor, test, build, ci, perf"
      exit 1
    fi
  displayName: 'Check commit message type'

I'm not a devops dev, if you have found alternative ways to solve this task, I would be glad to hear it. Thanks a lot in advance

If I understand correctly, you're trying to get the message before changes are merged into the target branch - am I correct?

@RuiJarimba exactly, I'm trying to get the pipeline run to throw an exception if the commit message format does not validate.

You can get the pull request commit message via rest api Pull Request Commits - Get Pull Request Commits.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/commits?api-version=7.1

Devops task sample：
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - checkout: none
  - powershell: |
      # Get the commits for the pull request
      $commitsUrl = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.Name)/pullRequests/$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)/commits?api-version=7.1"
      echo $commitsUrl
      $commitsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $commitsUrl -Method Get  -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
      # Extract and print the commit messages
      $commitMessages = $commitsResponse.value.comment
      $commitMessages
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(system.accesstoken)
    displayName: 'Get Pull Request Commit Messages'

It will grant all commit messages in Pull request as below:

If you would like only the latest commit message, add "`$top=1" in the url.
$commitsUrl = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.Name)/pullRequests/$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)/commits?`$top=1&api-version=7.1"



thanks a lot, this worked without further modifications needed on my side

Retrieving the pull request ID
You can use the $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId) pipeline variable to get the ID of the pull request, but please note that all  $(System.PullRequest.xxxxxx) variables are initialized only if the build ran because of a Git PR affected by a branch policy.
In other words, these variables are available for pipelines configured in the Build Validation section of the branch policy.

Retrieving the pull request information
The following Azure DevOps CLI commands can be used to retrieve pull request related info such as title, description, etc:

az repos pr list: List pull requests
az repos pr show: Get the details of a pull request

Please refer to Sign in with a personal access token (PAT) for more details regarding the Azure DevOps authentication.
Example pipeline
The following pipeline displays the name of the pull request in the logs, using a combination of Powershell and the Azure DevOps CLI commands described above:
# Use parameter when running the pipeline manually, e.g. for troubleshooting purposes
parameters:
  - name: pullRequestId
    type: string
    default: $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - name: "System.debug"
    value: true

steps:
  - checkout: none

  - pwsh: >-
      $pullRequestId = ${{ parameters.pullRequestId }}

      Write-Host "`nListing active pull requests for source branch $(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)"

      $activePullRequests = az repos pr list
      --org $(System.CollectionUri)
      --project $(System.TeamProject)
      --repository $(Build.Repository.Name)
      --source-branch $(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)
      --status active
      --query "[].{ id: pullRequestId, title: title }"
      --output json
      
      $activePullRequests

      Write-Host "`nTrying to get the title of the pull request with id $PullRequestId"

      $pullRequest = az repos pr show
      --id $pullRequestId
      --org $(System.CollectionUri)
      --output json
      | ConvertFrom-Json

      Write-Host "Pull request with ID $($pullRequest.pullRequestId) has title: $($pullRequest.title)"
    displayName: 'Display pull request title'
    env:
      AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)

Please note it's not required to use both az repos pr list and az repos pr show commands, but it might be useful to list all available pull requests for the target branch for troubleshooting purposes.
Running the pipeline:

